# My LTspice simulation results don't match the breadboard

Tags: ac, ltspice, breadboard, high-pass-filter, cutoff-frequency

I was testing a high pass filter like this. And here comes the simulation result on LTspice as well.

This is the AC analysis result followed by the transient analysis.

[image]

[image]

The 8Hz transient analysis input is chosen because as seen from the AC analysis result, the gain at 8Hz is around -6dB and it's easy to recognize in the transient analysis. The transient analysis does show that the gain remains -6dB (around Vout/Vin = 0.5).

Here is what I have on the breadboard.The 'output' is connected to an oscilloscope. The 'input' is connected to a signal generator which gives 1 Vpeak, 0 DC offset sine wave signal, and I was manually adjusting its frequency, changing continuously from 0.2 Hz to 30Hz. I wanted to validate the circuit at certain frequencies (1, 4, 10 and 30 Hz) to see if the gain matches the AC analysis result. But the Vout/Vin value didn't change at all and it was almost always 1 when I adjusted the frequency. Only when the frequency was very small (around 0.2~0.3 Hz), a slight change of the Vout/Vin value could be observed (the Vout/Vin fropped a little bit from 1 to 0.8).

[image]

I thought it might be because I was using a big input signal of 1 Vpeak and the AC analysis in LTspice is designed for small signal therefore the simulation might be wrong, so I tried simulating with transient analysis as well. As explained above, I think that the result of the transient analysis matches the AC analysis.

What could be the reason my circuit on the breadboard isn't working as the same as the simulation? I've made sure that each capacitor, resistor and wire is working well. Thanks for looking into this and thank you for any advice.

Comment: Please add a good photo of your breadboard setup.

Comment: A lot of your description doesn't match what's in your screenshot.  No where do I see something that's 1Vpp, they are all 1Vpeak.  Your `AC 1 0` command only affects `.ac` analysis.  Your `SINE (0 1)` only affects `.tran` analysis, but additionally, you're missing the 3rd parameter which is frequency.  Also, if you're doing a `.tran` you might have to let it run longer in case it needs to reach steady state.  You should also let us know which node you're trying to probe since `V(n002)` doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: Hi, I have added the picture in the description. Thank u!

Comment: Sorry I didn't put the good pictures and I have uploaded them in the description. I was using 1Vpeak all the time. The commands of AC analysis and transient analysis are as above, and I hope they are clearer now. Thanks for pointing out what's unclear in the description!

Comment: Is the oscilloscope AC or DC coupled? At 8 Hz you should use DC coupling as the low frequency corner frequency of an AC coupled oscilloscope input, often around 10 Hz, may be causing a measurement error.

Comment: I have checked on the oscilloscpe following your advice. It is DC coupled.